# Possibility of connecting MySQL database to Google Assistant

Tags: python, mysql, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

What I want to implement is at least a working prototype of a Google Assistant Action with the use of local MySQL database. What I've taught of is MySQL DB-> Google Cloud Platform-> DialogFlow -> Google Assistant.

So the end product would be for example, I say: "What is my total sales" and Google Assistant would retrieve the data from MySQL. I've been trying to look for solutions online and none seem to match what I am looking for. Would this solution be theoretically possible? and how would I be able to integrate the cloud platform into the Google Assistant Action through DialogFlow? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible!

1. Create a Dialogflow agent. Define your intents and add the static response. Test it.
2. Once tests are passed, integrated it with Actions-On-Google using "Integration tab" to the left.
3. Test the Assistant with static responses.
4. When Assistant is ready with the static response, [develop a webhook](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment). You can use different client libraries in NodeJS ([AoG Client](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) or [Dialogflow Client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs)) or in Python ([Flask-Assistant](https://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Dialogflow Client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2)) or can create your own.
5. Once the webhook is ready, run it locally and expose to the internet using [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/).
6. Use the generated URL as fulfillment to the Dialogflow agent and update the assistant's draft version.
7. Create a MySQL DB and connect it webhook using regular [NodeJS](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp) or [Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm) code
8. Restart the server and test end to end!
9. Once tested locally with NGROK, you can PUSH it to the cloud ([NodeJS](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world) or [Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/hello-world)) or any other server.