# Dialogflow and heroku Webhooks

Tags: node.js, heroku, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I have created a Dialogflow agent which is integrated with telegram bot. The bot answers all the questions to which is trained. Now I want to create a webhook to which the Dialogflow agent will fetch the queries ( e.g weather , movie ratings etc )say from another website.  How do i carry it out. I have googled but so far not successful. can any body suggest basic tutorial for the above or examples.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471128/possibility-of-connecting-mysql-database-to-google-assistant/51471645#51471645). Most of the part would be helpful. Once you tested it locally you may follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) to deploy NodeJS code on Heroku.